# Zsh preexec - How to trim all leading indentations from a codeblock?

Tags: sed, zsh, whitespace

Say I copy the following codeblock from a `.md` handbook which incldes some information and a few codeblocks (hence it's not a script file):

```
⇨⇨⇨⇨(
⇨⇨⇨⇨Indented commands...
⇨⇨⇨⇨)
```

The Zsh `preexec` function could be used to remove all leading whitespaces (usually tabulations but maybe also spaces) from this original codeblock, and return a unindented version of it:

```
(
commands...
)
```

As far as I understand, the preexec action should include `'s/^\s*//g'`.

Please share how you would achieve this goal with preexec.

Comment: How does leading spaces make it not a script file? Leading spaces has no effect on how a script runs. "The Zsh preexec could be used to remove all leading whitespaces" -- No it cannot. Perhaps you can explain what it is you're trying to accomplish. Are you wanting to copy/paste code with leading tabs into your terminal?

Comment: @Patrick, leading blanks can be significant when inside multi-line quoted strings, or in here documents.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, but you can also argue that blindly removing leading spaces can break things, such as in multi-line quoted strings or here documents.

Comment: @Patrick, I'll agree with that. Though the OP seems to have a special case in mind. See his other recent questions.

Comment: Related question by the OP that may bring some context: [Making a FIFO that strips all leading whitespaces?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/362645)

Comment: Yes @Patrick I do have copy/paste code with leading tabs that I want to execute in the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it in `preexec` would be too late. By that time, the code has already been parsed. If you modify it, it would need to be parsed again (and possibly, `zsh` would need to prompt for more lines to finish the code).

Possibly here you can do it in the `accept-line` widget, that is just before the line editor feeds the line to the shell parser:

```
accept-line() {
  emulate -L zsh       # default zsh behaviour locally
  set -o extendedglob  # with extendedglob for ## (= ERE +) below

  BUFFER=${BUFFER##[[:blank:]]##} # remove leading blanks

  # remove blanks after newlines in case a multiline buffer is accepted
  # for instance after a safe-paste or a newline entered with <Alt+Ret>
  BUFFER=${BUFFER//$'\n'[[:blank:]]##/$'\n'}

  # call original accept-line
  zle .$WIDGET
}
zle -N accept-line
```

Comment: If someone works crossplatform from Windows it might consider doing this before the content is copied to Linux, as in this AutoHotkey solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1205075/how-to-strip-leading-tabs-and-or-leading-spaces-when-copying-data-to-clipboard